# Nested infer returns unknown on conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-conditional-types

My code will speak better that my words:

```
type Id<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
type RemoveMethods<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends (...args: any) => any ? never : P]: T[P] }

type Foo = Bar<{ title: string }>

export declare class Bar<T> {
    foo: string;
    fn1(arg: T): T
}

type Baz = Foo extends Id<Bar<infer U>> ? U : never; // OK
//   ^?

type Baz2 = Foo extends RemoveMethods<Bar<infer U>> ? U : never; // KO
//   ^?

type Baz3 = Foo extends Bar<infer U> ? U : never; // KO
//   ^?
```

Why does the infer fails to return `{ title: string }` when using `RemoveMethods`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgHgCoD4oF4oG8oG0AKUAlgHZQDWEIA9gGZRIC6AXAwY1AL4CwAUKJCgAlCAFtqANwgBZCMAAW1OAGdkaTDgLEylGvSRQAhsrb4OEAB7AIJFVAAUAOmeGATgHNlrQyRABKDDQfECgAfigSCClXKFYzViR2Lj4+AWgAMWpqDCgAITcEHGAiYAAbCFZlYFdSdy4UFN5LMGpXYCg4CABjUrdoHuMTfNc1bD4oCahaLMrq2oBuccnaEgBGezd3BL8Evh5eVPBofIAvHMzsy2tbE3gEYYRSWggYgFUUNHDX2Iiol-moAB6QFQADyAGk+MDJgA9UKNNJ5QwnABM5yyUCuNjsInEUlkCiUqgeTxeUHen3JP0i0QB0PBoKhIImcIRRyRJwAzOjLlZsUMCqS3pTvqwaf8gSCGUzYfCDrwgA)

Comment: If you remove `fn1(arg: T): T` from the class, then where is TS supposed to infer the generic from? It's not `any` since you clearly passed `infer U`, too.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. If `foo` is of type `T` I still have this problem.

Comment: Inference from mapped types only works when the mapped type is *homomorphic* (so you might be able to infer `T` from `{[K in keyof T]: F<T>}`), and remapped keys are no longer homomorphic.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up the answer; if not, what am I missing? (Side note, you probably should go ahead and make `foo` of type `T` and maybe even not have `fn1`, to remove distractions)

Comment: If you have a solution to infer U after having removing the methods from the type, I'm interested !

Comment: This question isn't asking for a solution, it's asking "why does the inference fail"?  If you want a solution you should [edit] the question to ask that instead, but it seems like scope creep.